# Model Mapper, what is the best way to abstract common code, i.e. helpers, decorators

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, mapper

Using Zend (1 or 2), what is the best way to abstract common code in the model mappers? In the controller/view there are the relevant helpers, what about in the mappers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to base my mappers on two examples:

1. [Survive the Deep End](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors) by Padraic Brady
2. [Dasprid's blog source](http://site.svn.dasprids.de/trunk/)

Padraic allows each mapper to compose other mappers, keeping the code DRY and focusing each mapper on precisely those database fields it needs to know about.

Dasprid's uses a base mapper class to contain common code for handling the db connection.

Together, there should be enough places to keep common code.

Of course, the [Doctrine2 ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) manages most of this via configuration. After several only-half-satisfying attempts to do mapping myself, I have found myself happier with Doctrine.

Comment: Dasprid informs me that the svn repo for his blog is no longer publicly accessible. (sad)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a class in your library or wherever you store common code, perhaps something like:

```
//library/My/Model/Mapper/Abstract.php
<?php

abstract class My_Model_Mapper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Instance of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
     *
     * @var Zend_Db_Table_Abstract $tableGateway
     */
    protected $tableGateway = null;
    /**
     * sets up the identity map
     */
    protected $map          = array();

    /**
     * Will accept a DbTable model passed or will instantiate
     * a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract object from table name.
     *
     * @param Zend_Db_Table_Abstract $tableGateway
     */
    public function __construct(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract $tableGateway = null)
    {
        if (is_null($tableGateway)) {
            $this->tableGateway = new Zend_Db_Table($this->tableName);
        } else {
            $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the default database table adapter.
     *
     * @return Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
     */
    protected function getGateway()
    {
        return $this->tableGateway;
    }

    //truncated for space

    public function findById($id)
    {
        if ($this->getMap($id)) {
            return $this->getMap($id);
        }

        $select = $this->getGateway()->select();
        $select->where('id = ?', $id);

        $row = $this->getGateway()->fetchRow($select);

        $entity = $this->createEntity($row);

        $this->setMap($row->id, $entity);

        return $entity;
    }

    //truncated for space

    /**
     * Abstract method to be implemented by concrete mappers.
     */
    abstract protected function createEntity($row);
}
```

Then a concrete implementation might resemble:

```
//application/modules/users/model/mappers/User.php
<?php

class Users_Model_Mapper_User extends My_Model_Mapper_Abstract
{
    protected $tableName = 'users';

    public function __construct(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract $tableGateway = null)
    {
        if (is_null($tableGateway)) {
            //TODO: inject this resource
            $tableGateway = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
        } else {
            $tableGateway = $tableGateway;
        }

        parent::__construct($tableGateway);
    }

    protected function createEntity($row)
    {
        $data = array(
            'id'       => $row->id,
            'username' => $row->username,
            'password' => $row->password
        );
        $user = new Users_Model_User($data);

        return $user;
    }

    private function hashPassword($password)
    {
        return Password::createPasswordHash($password);
    }

    public function saveUser(My_Model_Entity_Abstract $user)
    {
        if (!is_null($user->id)) {

            $select = $this->getGateway()->select();
            $select->where('id = ?', $user->id);

            $row = $this->getGateway()->fetchRow($select);
        } else {
            $row = $this->getGateway()->createRow();
            $row->password = $this->hashPassword($user->password);
        }
        $row->username = $user->username;

        $row->save();
        return $row;
    }
}
```

These are created to utilize the DbTable Models commonly used in ZF1 and are still works in progress.

ZF2 models may be somewhat different as ZF2 implements and extends much more of the PHP SPL library so some modification will likely be useful.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to use a design pattern rather than a private/protected method to use the mapping in multiple places. As it will also be used in different mapping classes. Moving it to the abstract class is not ideal either.

Comment: I'm sorry but your reply makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: For example:
\Mapper\Item uses \Entity\Item,
\Mapper\User uses \Entity\Item. 
So both of these mappers use the same entity (as well as others) & will contain very similar mapping code, i.e. $itemEntity->setName($name) x5+ lines. 
I would like to abstract these 5+ lines out so all mappers can benefit from this code.

Comment: isn't that what I said? The abstract mapper encompasses all of the code common to all mappers but allows concrete instances to be implemented to allow for deviations. Also I left out the entity side of things as that wasn't your question.

Comment: The mapper is mostly made up of different entity setters/getters, to move this to parent class would not be right - it would abuse inheritance / pollute the parent class.

Comment: No the entity model is made up of setter/getters the mapper provides access to a data store, then uses that data to create entities. the only getter in my example is the getGateway() method which is a proxy for the database connection. These classes consume a database connection or some other data store and generate entities of a specific type.

Comment: apologies, as I re-read my post I realised it was not clear. But we are both on the same page. Yes the entity is made up of setters/getters, but the mappers use the entity's setters/getter. i.e. $entity->setName('aaa')->setTitle('bbb'); and this repeated throughout the mapper & other mappers (i.e. findAll, findById etc)

Answer (score 0):

Hydrators look like an interesting solution http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html